# Java Dialog Box Icons

Tags: java

What do you need to add to select various icons for dialog boxes? Also how do you use a custom icon?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean `JDialog`s? If so, you're looking for [this page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#features) from the Java Tutorials. Copied below are the samples from that page, without the screenshots; see the last one for how to use a custom icon:

```
//default title and icon
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
    "Eggs are not supposed to be green.", 
    "Message");

//custom title, warning icon
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
    "Eggs are not supposed to be green.",
    "Inane warning",
    JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

//custom title, error icon
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
    "Eggs are not supposed to be green.",
    "Inane error",
    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

//custom title, no icon
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
    "Eggs are not supposed to be green.",
    "A plain message",
    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

//custom title, custom icon
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
    "Eggs are not supposed to be green.",
    "Inane custom dialog",
    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icon);
```

In that last example, `icon` is an object of type `Icon`. Here's [the Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon%29) for that version of `showMessageDialog()`.

Comment: Next you're going to say ham isn't supposed to green either. >:|

Comment: @RBemrose _Notice to Consumer: Consuming green eggs and/or ham may increase your risk of foodborne illness, especially if you have certain medical conditions. Consult your physician or public health official for further information._